# Cannot build Android after adding FireBase Database Package

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I imported FireBases Database Unity Package today and as part of the import it had to various upgrades (such as a .NET upgrade and installation of some Android packages.

My game builds and runs fine in the Unity editor, however trying to build the game for Android I get the following error.

I was fully able to build the game prior to importing the package.

After some looking around  about this issue I found this bug on the Unity page: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unity-tries-to-find-a-not-existing-classes-dot-jar-file-in-play-services-dot-aar-which-results-in-failing-android-build

However I am no closer as to saving this issue.

[image]

I am using the latest version of Unity 2017.3.1f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I was able to find an answer.

Setting the build settings to Gradle and adding a Build.Gradle file in the root of the project was able to solve my issue.

This question was a duplicate of the following: 
[(Firebase Databse in Unity) missing classes.jar in Temp during build for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130395/firebase-databse-in-unity-missing-classes-jar-in-temp-during-build-for-android)